# how to add value to an existing column in a Dataset for a particular row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

"ds" is of type dataset having existing column inpMap. Need to know how can I add value for a particular row to this column of dataset

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        
                         String propMap = "abc";
        
                         if(propMap != null){
                             String inpMap = colMap.get(propMap); // where colMap is dictionary
                             ds= ds.withColumn(inpMap, "test"); // ??? how to do here...as withCol adds new col. And I have this col existing in "ds" Dataset.
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: if the column exists, `withColumn` will replace that column, so it's fine to use `withColumn` here.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Spark, it is best if you try to visualize the transformations creating columns rather than rows. This makes building the logic easier.

As per your code, I assume that the variable **"propMap"** is unchanging. You simply write the transformation as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

String inpMap = colMap.get(propMap);
dsWithTestColumn = ds.withColumn("test", lit(inpMap));
```

Also I am assuming that you are using Java API with Apache Spark.